# is it possible to get user's input to multiple txtfields [by getText()] and then concatenate it?

Tags: java, concatenation, string-concatenation

is it possible to get user's input to multiple txtfields [by getText()] and then concatenate it?
Say, I have 5 txtfields and I would like to get the letter he inputted to each txtfield and then compare it to the right word (it's like a 4pics1word game).

```
        String s1 = field1.getText();
        String s2 = field2.getText();
        String s3 = field3.getText();
        String s4 = field4.getText();
        String s5 = field5.getText();

        if (s1 + s2 + s3 + s4 + s5 == "hello") {
            lvl++;
        }
```

Is this even possible? (Lol. Sorry I'm a beginner)
And if not, what would you suggest I'd do instead? Thank you

Comment: You just did it (except for the way you compare the result to "hello"), why would it be impossible ? If you want more information about the behaviour of == for strings, you may be interested by looking the doc of the String.intern(à method.

Comment: You have the solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. You do it almost right:

```
String result = s1 + s2 + s3 + s4 + s5;
if ("hello".equals(result) {
  lvl++;
}
```

And if you venture into more field, you should look into `StringBuilder`:

```
String result = new StringBuilder().append(s1).append(s2).append(s3).append(s4).append(s5).toString();
if ("hello".equals(result) {
  lvl++;
}
```

And with Java 8:

```
String result = Arrays.asList(field1, field2, field3, field4, field5)
                      .stream()
                      .map(field -> field.getText()) // or ClassOfField::getText
                      .collect(Collectors.joining());
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's entirely possible. The only problem with your code is that you're using `==` to compare strings, which almost never works (for comparing their contents). Use `.equals`:

```
if ("hello".equals(s1 + s2 + s3 + s4 + s5) {
```

Using `==` with string objects compares object references. You can have more than one string object that has the same sequence of characters, so that's what `equals` is for. In Java, you basically never use `==` with strings.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is completely possible. Note, however, that string comparisons should be done with `equals`, not `==`:

```
if ((s1 + s2 + s3 + s4 + s5).equals("hello")) {
  lvl++;
}
```